# Get json list hosted on gihub - doesn't push into html

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, getjson

I'm trying to pull a content from a json file which is hosted on external server, into html.
Here is what I have so far but no success.

```
    var myurl = "https://gist.github.com/Keeguon/2310008/raw/865a58f59b9db2157413e7d3d949914dbf5a237d/countries.json";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(myurl,
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].code + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: By unsuccessful do you mean you are not getting anything back or it's wrong, etc..?

Comment: No success with what exactly? Replace the `for` counting loop with `for (var item in json)` - but this will not solve whatever problem you've got.

Comment: Yes, the html is blank, and I also get this from console:Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Comment: First of all, the linked file is *not* valid JSON. JSON keys must be enclosed in strings.

Comment: How should it be then, @AndrewWhitaker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're trying to make a cross-domain AJAX request which is not allowed under [the same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) policy.
2. The "JSON" you're trying to load is not valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json).

I'd recommend using the [Github API here along with a JSONP request](http://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks). I'd also recommend using [this fork of the gist](https://gist.github.com/almost/7748738) you linked to. With that in mind:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/7748738',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
        var countriesStr = response.data.files['countries.json'].content
            , countries = JSON.parse(countriesStr);

        // countries is an array of countries.
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WUAKu/1/

Comment: Cool, that's very impressive you found out in such short time.

Answer (score 0):

To Andrew Whitaker's point the JSON is not valid. The keys must be enclosed in strings.

```
{'name': 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
...
```

Also, making an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than the one your site is on will be blocked by default for security reasons. So you need to do something different when making a cross-domain request. Here is a great tutorial using [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

To quote the [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html):

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and
>   receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same
>   origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to
>   remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests
>   cross-origin permissions.